# aggregate totals when key changes in Perl

Tags: algorithm, perl, aggregate, pseudocode

I have an input file with the following format

```
ant,1
bat,1
bat,2
cat,4
cat,1
cat,2
dog,4
```

I need to aggregate the col2 for each key (column1) so the result is:

```
ant,1
bat,3
cat,7
dog,4
```

Other considerations:

1. Assume that the input file is sorted
2. The input file is pretty large (about 1M rows), so I don't want to use an array and take up memory
3. Each input line should be processed as we read it, and move to the next line
4. I need to write the results to an outFile
5. I need to do this in Perl, but a pseudo-code or algorithm would help just as fine

Thanks!

This is what I came up with... want to see if this can be written better/elegant.

```
open infile, outFile

prev_line = <infile>;
print_line = $prev_line;

while(<>){
   curr_line = $_;

   @prev_cols=split(',', $prev_line);
   @curr_cols=split(',', $curr_line);

   if ( $prev_cols[0] eq $curr_cols[0] ){
      $prev_cols[1] += curr_cols[1];
      $print_line = "$prev_cols[0],$prev_cols[1]\n";
      $print_flag = 0;
   }
   else{
      $print outFile "$print_line";
      $print_flag = 1;
      $print_line = $curr_line;
   }
   $prev_line = $curr_line;
}

if($print_flag = 1){
   print outFile "$curr_line";
}   
else{
   print outFile "$print_line";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use integer;

my %a;
while (<>) {
    my ($animal, $n) = /^\s*(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+)/;
    $a{$animal} += $n if defined $n;
}
print "$_,${a{$_}}\n" for sort keys %a;
```

This short code affords you the chance to learn Perl's excellent *hash* facility, as `%a`.  Hashes are central to Perl.  One really cannot write fluent Perl without them.

Observe incidentally that the code exercises Perl's interesting *autovivification* feature.  The first time a particular animal is encountered in the input stream, no count exists, so Perl implicitly assumes a pre-existing count of zero.  Thus, the `+=` operator does not fail, even though it seems that it should.  It just adds to zero in the first instance.

On the other hand, it may happen that not only the number of data but *the number of animals* is so large that one would not like to store the hash `%a`.  In this case, one can still calculate totals, provided only that the data are sorted by animal in the input, as they are in your example.  In this case, something like the following might suit (though regrettably it is not nearly so neat as the above).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use integer;

my $last_animal = undef;
my $total_for_the_last_animal = 0;

sub start_new_animal ($$) {
    my $next_animal = shift;
    my $n = shift;
    print "$last_animal,$total_for_the_last_animal\n"
      if defined $last_animal;
    $last_animal = $next_animal;
    $total_for_the_last_animal = $n;
}

while (<>) {
    my ($animal, $n) = /^\s*(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+)/;
    if (
        defined($n) && defined($animal) && defined($last_animal)
          && $animal eq $last_animal
    ) { $total_for_the_last_animal += $n; }
    else { start_new_animal $animal, $n; }
}
start_new_animal undef, 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That works well.  But then we load all the data into memory (in hash)... right?  What if I have a huge file that I'm avoiding to load into memory?  The solution was very elegant.  I will need to learn more on Perl hashes.

Comment: It is true that the hash keeps one entry each for the ant, the bat, the cat and the dog.  However, the hash keeps only one running total for the ant, only one running total for the bat, and so on.  It does not store each line of the input.  Does your application bring so many *different kinds* of animals that even keeping one running total per animal is unreasonable?

Comment: Yes, the number of unique keys will be very large.  I can not put everything into a hash.  For smaller sets, the solution would work well.

Comment: I see.  Does your input guarantee that all the ants will appear in sequence, followed by all the bats, etc.? or is it possible that ants, bats, cats and dogs will all be interleaved?

Comment: I will sort the input file (using unix sort), so the order is guaranteed.

Comment: I see.  This is a bit harder.  Stand by.

Comment: Thanks!  I wrote a Perl script for this and was not happy with the algorithm I came up with.  Used flags etc. to figure out which line to print.  So, wanted to check if there's a better solution.

Comment: Try the second script above, just added.  Good luck.  By the way, under the restriction that keys not be stored, I cannot do without flags and such any better than you can, regrettably.

Comment: Thanks thb!!  Can you take a look at my code I've added just now, and comment on it?

Comment: Your algorithm looks identical to mine.  Perl's motto is "There's more than one way to do it," so the two scripts *look* different, but I don't think that they really are.  The only substantive difference I see does not amount to much:  the line `$print outFile "$print_line";` appears twice in your code -- once within the loop and once without.  I tend to be compulsive about avoiding such repetition, which is why I have defined the function `start_new_animal()` to do the job, and then called the function twice.  But I couldn't avoid special handling after the loop any more than you could.

Comment: Thanks thb!  Makes me feel better that I was not totally offbase with my algorithm.  Appreciate your comments and help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Perl’s [*awk* mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-a%2a).

> - **-a**
>
> turns on autosplit mode when used with a `-n` or `-p`. An implicit `split` command to the `@F` array is done as the first thing inside the implicit `while` loop produced by the `-n` or `-p`.
>
> ```
> perl -ane 'print pop(@F), "\n";'
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>   @F = split(' ');
>   print pop(@F), "\n";
> }
> ```
>
> An alternate delimiter may be specified using `-F`.

All that’s left for you is to accumulate the sums in a hash and print them.

```
$ perl -F, -lane '$s{$F[0]} += $F[1];
    END { print "$_,$s{$_}" for sort keys %s }' input
```

Output:

```
ant,1
bat,3
cat,7
dog,4
```

Comment: Thanks Greg.  But my limitation is that my input file will be huge and I don't want to use a hash as there will be too many unique keys.  So, I need to process each line as it comes in... i.e, print it if the next key is different or aggregate it if the key is same.  Please comment on my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial in perl.  Loop on the file input.  Split the input line on comma.  For each key in column one keep a hash to which you add the value in column two.  At the end of the file print the list of hash keys and their values.  It can be done in one line but that would obfuscate the algorithm.